# Is there any way to "slow down" TRIGGERS?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Im working with **PL/SQL** in **Oracle SQL Developer** 3.2.2, using **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition**.

So far I have created few tables: Population and Sectors.

```
CREATE TABLE sectores (
  codS NUMBER(2),
  nombreS VARCHAR2(20),
  porcentS NUMBER(5,2),
  ingresosS NUMBER(9,2),
  num_pob NUMBER(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (codS)
);

CREATE TABLE poblacion (
  dni VARCHAR2(9), 
  nombre VARCHAR(12), 
  apellido1 VARCHAR2(12), 
  apellido2 VARCHAR2(12),
  fechanac DATE,
  direccion VARCHAR2(20),
  cp VARCHAR2(5),
  sexo VARCHAR2(1),
  ingresos NUMBER(7,2),
  gastosFijos NUMBER(7,2), 
  gastosAlim NUMBER(7,2), 
  gastosRopa NUMBER(7,2), 
  sector NUMBER(2), 
  PRIMARY KEY (dni),
  FOREIGN KEY (sector) REFERENCES sectores (codS) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

So people in "Population" will be linked in a way to sectors.
My intention is to dectect any moment I have more than 3 persons in the same Sector.

Whenever I insert a new person in Population, I'm increasing num_pob from Sectors by 1. I do that with this TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ingresosS1 
AFTER INSERT ON poblacion 
REFERENCING NEW AS NUEVA
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NUEVA.sector IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
  UPDATE sectores
  SET ingresosS = ingresosS + :NUEVA.ingresos
  WHERE codS = :NUEVA.sector;
  
  UPDATE sectores
  SET num_pob = 1 + (SELECT num_pob FROM sectores WHERE codS = :NUEVA.sector)
  WHERE codS = :NUEVA.sector;
  
  UPDATE sectores 
  SET porcentS = 100 * ingresosS / (SELECT SUM(ingresosS) FROM sectores);
END;
/
```

I checked this, so far and everything works fine.
Now, I declare this TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER muchaGente
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sectores
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.codS IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE 
    counter INTEGER;
    numPOB INTEGER;
BEGIN
  counter := :OLD.num_pob;
    numPOB := counter - 1;
    IF 3 < counter
        THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:' || :NEW.codS );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:' || numPOB ||', ahora:' || :OLD.num_pob );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

This one should help me out writting in the screen everytime I surpase the 3 person mark. When I insert 4 persons in the same sectors, it works perfectly. This is my Log after inserting 4 persons:

> Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:1
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:3, ahora:4

However, and here comes the issue... After Dropping the tables and create them again, when I insert 5 persons, Im getting this in the log:

> Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:1
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:3, ahora:4
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:1
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:3, ahora:4
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:1
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:3, ahora:4
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Hay más de 3 personas en el sector:1
>
> Trigger muchaGente: Antes había:4, ahora:5

This has 0 sense. I guess somehow the Triggers are fast enough to mess up the logs in my screen, do you guys know anyway to fix this? Maybe the last one TRIGGER has an error, but I don't see any...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67327)  places the strings in the buffer. These are only displayed when control returns to the client.The output cannot be retrieved until the PL/SQL program unit from which it was buffered returns to its caller.

You should consider raising an exception when your condition (num_pob per sector > 3) is satisfied.

Rewriting your triggers.

**Trigger1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ingresosS1 
AFTER INSERT ON poblacion 
REFERENCING NEW AS NUEVA
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NUEVA.sector IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
  UPDATE sectores
  SET ingresosS = ingresosS + :NUEVA.ingresos
  WHERE codS = :NUEVA.sector;

  UPDATE sectores
   SET num_pob = COALESCE(num_pob,0) + 1 
  WHERE codS = :NUEVA.sector;

  UPDATE sectores 
  SET porcentS = COALESCE(100 * ingresosS / (SELECT SUM(ingresosS) FROM sectores),0);
END;
/
```

**Trigger2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER muchaGente
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sectores
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.codS IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE 
    counter INTEGER;
    numPOB INTEGER;
BEGIN
   counter  := :OLD.num_pob;
    numPOB  := counter - 1;
    IF counter > 3
        THEN 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
                             'There are more than 3 persons in the same Sector' );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

So, when the condition is met, it will raise an exception

> ORA-20001: There are more than 3 persons in the same Sector

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d0322c72f0a5413c94917ebbf20e1230)

Comment: Woah, 1 week ago I was working with Exceptions but I didn't know I could use them here. Thanks for the solution and the explanation at the beggining! <3